# Managing back office and front office of website

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, backend, web-frontend

I'm working to a project and my aim is to create an **html page** to view the train/bus/tram timeboards.

So there is one `html` page for **back-office**(for the company) and one page for **front-office**(for the customers).

The company wants to change files in the page (pdf/links that can be viewed inpage) from back-office.

How can i **manage the informations** between back-office and front-office by using some simple stuff/programming languages?
Anyone has an idea?

Substantially I want to do something like this for front-office view:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NGxrQp `<--Check this`

OR

http://jsbin.com/mawevuwi/1#tab4

And then something more simple for back-office.

PS: I'm new at stackoverflow and sorry for my bad english explanation.

Comment: You would need some sort of content management system. The contents of the tabs could be populated from a feed (json/xml) for example (depending if you're using an api to pull in this information)

Comment: store the data , use CRUD operations in back end and pull from same data source in front end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A back-office should be able to add, edit or delete content. Therefor you should use dynamic webpages, not static. You can use a database to store values. Make the front-office read-only and you're done.

You could also use a `Content Management System (CMS)` like [WordPress](http://wordpress.com).

Some more info:

A static webpage only shows what's in the files. A dynamic webpage could show you generated data or data not in the file itself but from a database for example. Databases use SQL (Structured Query Language). The 4 operations are abbreviated as **`CRUD`**:

- **C**reate
- **R**ead
- **U**pdate
- **D**elete

I recommand you start learning SQL & PHP if you want to continue with this. Other languages (rather than PHP) are possible.

Comment: Ok thank you so much for the suggestions!

Comment: Other well-known CMS's are Joomla or Drupal.
For learning languages I would recommand http://www.w3schools.com/